# ActiveRecord query using 'includes' sometimes applies the default_scope, and sometimes doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, default-scope

I am trying to perform an ActiveRecord query on my User model that uses `includes` to eager-load users' roles and locations. (A user has many roles and has many locations)
The Location model has a default scope. It is:

`where(:status => [0, 2])`

When I perform a simple query with `includes`, the default scope on the Location model is applied. For example, the query:

`User.includes(:roles, :locations)`

Will contain the following in the sql output:

`SELECT "locations".*, "t0"."user_id" AS ar_association_key_name FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "locations_users" "t0" ON "locations"."id" = "t0"."location_id" WHERE "locations"."status" IN (0, 2)`

However, a slightly more complex query, such as:

`User.includes(:roles, :locations).where(roles: {id: 13})`

Does not apply the Location default scope. Locations with a status of `1` are being included in the users' returned locations.

I notice the first query is performed with multiple `SELECT` statements, whereas the 2nd query is performed all as one `SELECT` statement with many `JOIN`s. How can I make it so the default_scope is applied in all cases?

I am using Rails 3.2.22.